# Java GUI with scrolling text and images

Tags: java, image, swing, text, scroll

How do I create a GUI with a scrolling text area and underneath small paragraphs of text there are corresponding images?

I am currently using a `JTextArea` with a scroll-bar to display the text and it works great, but I want to display the corresponding images underneath each small paragraph of text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [javax.swing.JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html)

Check [TextSamplerDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TextSamplerDemo)

You can find plenty of examples here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TextPaneSample.htm

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, would be to use `JEditorPane` with `HTMLEditorKit`You can use HTML text formnatting including graphics, just like a webpage.